# Special 404 header page

Tags: page-template

I wonder if there is a specific way to create a custom 404 header template.

This can be done for secondary page, but creating a header-404.php doesn't do the trick.

Am I really supposed to create an if in the main header checking whether the is_404() returns true?

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: That specific example is covered on [the Codex page for `get_header()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header). TL;DR: `if( is_404() ) { get_header( '404' ); }` ... in which case, it will use `header-404.php`.

Answer (score 1):

As said in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header#Multiple_Headers)

`header-404.php` is **not** auto loaded on `404.php` template, you have to create it but also call the header using

```
get_header( '404' );
```

instead of `get_header()`.

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment:

I ran across a very similar issue with `get_sidebar()`, which I expected (incorrectly) to work the same as `get_template_part()`.  A work-around is to do something like this:

```
// instead of using get_header( '404' ); , do this:
get_template_part( 'header', '404' );
// which should select 'header-404.php', or, if it doesn't
// exist, fail over to 'header.php'
```

### References

- [`get_header()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header)
- [`get_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar)
- [`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)